# Dynamic Add Row to MVC View then pass to controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, partial-views

Okay, so I've tried a ton of things, none of which I'm very familiar with, and I can't seem to figure out exactly how to get done what I need to do. It seems like a simple task, and I'm sure someone has done it!

In essence, I need to create a form that has the ability to create more fields that will bind to the model, or even just pass to the controller on submit.

First, I have a model that is pretty straightforward. Something like:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public List<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
}
public class UserModel
{
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public bool UserIsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

My view is a simple signup form that takes all the input necessary to create an account. It needs to have these fields, but also be able to have a link that says "add User" and ajax in another row with first name, last name, email, and isAdmin flag.

This is where I get stuck. I'm thinking I need something with a partial view and a custom binding to a controller as the data gets passed in, but I can't figure out how to pass in an object that contains all the users so I can iterate through it.

If anyone could even **point** me in the right direction, I would be very happy.

-Lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend reading [Phil Haacked - Model Binding to a List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).  His example could easily be extended to use Ajax.

Comment: Oh my gosh. That article was a breath of fresh air and exactly what I needed to sort this out. Turns out I was incredibly close to the correct answer yesterday, and even had my view populating via ajax with incremented indices in the input names. I just didn't know how to bind it to my model. Gotta love Phil Haack

Answer (score 1):

You could just create the model in JSON and send it to the controller:

JS:

```
var account = {
    Organization: // get from form or wherever
    Users: []
}

$('#submit').click(function() {   

    // loop through each new user div and append to the account object 
    $('.new-user').each(function() {
        var $newUser = $(this);
        Account.Users.push({
            UserFirstName: $newUser.find('.first-name').val(),
            UserLastName: $newUser.find('.last-name').val(),
            ...
        });
    });

    // ajax call to submit form with data: { Account: account }
});
```

HTML

```
<form ...>
   <!-- registration fields -->

   <!-- dynamically added new user fields - wrap in parent element -->
   <div class="new-user">
       <input class="first-name" type="text" />
       <input class="last-name" type="text" />
       ...
   </div>

   <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```